# Problem in digestion

Tags: diet

Basically I am software engineer so daily 8 hours I work by sitting only. There is no hard work , walking and anything.

So now I am getting problem in digestion. Doctors says you have to do some hard work for proper food digestion. I noticed that if I do regular GYM then digestion issue getting solve. But I want to know permanent solution. Any good recommendation?

Of course I will not do gym lifetime. :)

Comment: try to walk instead of taking a cab if your office is near or right after you wake up.

Comment: @Kerppag - Thanks but office it too far..:(

Comment: well at least walk 1-2 blocks from your office just to make your body active. Everyday I walk after I wake up and then walk myself to office(vice versa going home)

Comment: @Kerppag - yeap. that seems good idea.

Comment: Isn't working out a permanent solution? It's just as permanent as "taking showers to be clean" is, you'll have to do it all the time, but in some sense it's still permanent.

Comment: @Mårten - Yes you are right...it require regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with @Ker p pag about walking. Just an 30 min to an hour will help, but it may not be enough. Drink things like green tea, in the morning and evening and maybe a cup of coffee or tea while on lunch. Green tea will help your metabolism a lot.

Eating fibrous foods will also help, like oatmeal, broccoli etc.

Training a minimum of 3 times a week would be required at least. But that is the bare minimum, anything under that is a waste of time in my opinion.

And lastly water, drink a lot of water. At least 2-3 liters a day. Not juice, not milk but water.

Following these steps should be enough to make you go to the toilet once a day.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice answer. can you tell me that 30 min walking at morning OR after dinner/lunch?

Comment: Preferably in the mornings on an empty stomach. But nothing more than a walk on an empty stomach. Doing heavy cardio can be counter productive like that.

Comment: in addition to @s3v3ns answer try to workout on weekends. make it a habbit to make your body active if you're lazy to workout then do outdoor games just to stretch your body.